# Avro serialization hanging on DataFileWriter close method

Tags: avro

I am trying to use avro serialization but when I have multiple records to serialize, the application hangs on DataFileWriter close method, however it works with a small amount of records.

```
    final PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(
            pipedOutputStream);

    DatumWriter<DW> userDatumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<DW>(DW.class);
    DataFileWriter<DW> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<DW>(
            userDatumWriter);

    dataFileWriter.create(payload.get(0).getSchema(), pipedOutputStream);

    for (DW currentRecord : payload) {
        dataFileWriter.append(currentRecord);
    }

    dataFileWriter.close();
    return pipedInputStream;
```

I tried to flush after adding 10 records at a time, but then it hangs on the flush method.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by returning a ByteArrayOutputStream as follows:

```
    Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(DW.class);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ReflectDatumWriter<Object> reflectDatumWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter<Object>(
            schema);
    DataFileWriter<Object> writer = new DataFileWriter<Object>(
            reflectDatumWriter).create(schema, outputStream);
    for (DW currentRecord : payload) {
        writer.append(currentRecord);
    }

    writer.close();
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
```